# How do I install and run SEXTANTE for QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin, qgis-processing

I just upgraded to QGIS 2.0, and I have been unable to locate/use SEXTANTE tools.  A search with the plugin installer does not turn up anything for "sextante."  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sextante is now called `Processing` and has become a core feature of QGIS 2.0.

You can still load experimental versions of the plugin under it's new name.

Comment: How do I use it from the console?  And where are the SAGA and GRASS commands I used to use through SEXTANTE?

Comment: The new Menu entry `Processing` has a `toolbox` and a `commander` entry. Should be what you are used to. For using SAGA, it must be installed separately, and the path must be given under Options.

Comment: I'm used to using a side-pane toolbox with tree widgets you could expand for SAGA, GRASS, etc.  The commander seems to rely on my knowing the precise names for commands, and I don't. ...EDIT: oh, wait, I see that there's a pull-down tool now.  That helps...

Comment: I also don't understand what I need to do to install SAGA.

Comment: Getting the interface I expected required switching from "simplified interface" to "advanced interface" for the toolbox.

Comment: You can get SAGA from http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/. Just extract it, and tell Processing where it can find the files.

Comment: It showed up in the toolbox on its own... it did not need to be installed separately after all!

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to use Processing tools through the console.  Any help there?

Comment: It shows up in the menu, but won't work unless it is fully installed :-( The console I have never used before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12332/discussion-between-user21412-and-andre-joost)

Comment: Sorry, chat is not my world.

Answer (score -3):

processing toolbox can be achieved by installing processing plugin

Comment: It's true it was renamed, but it is also bundled like Sextante was once properly released. We're looking for longer, more elaborate answers that explain and widen knowledge.